# How do I reference method parameters in a method summary when writing XML documentation?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, sandcastle, xml-documentation

Suppose I have a method as follows:

```
    /// <summary>
    /// Here I want to reference the parameter <see cref="personId"/>.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="personId">
    /// The person id.
    /// </param>
    /// <returns>
    /// The <see cref="Person"/>.
    /// </returns>
    public Person GetPerson(int personId)
    {
        
    }
```

When I publish my XML documentation using Sandcastle, the cref:

```
<see cref="personId"/>
```

gets converted to **[!:personId]**.

The warning in Sandcastle is:

> Unknown reference link target

Any advice?

Comment: [For future use, a list of XML doc tags](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/5ast78ax%28v=vs.100%29.aspx)

Answer (score 47, accepted):

Use [`<paramref>`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/xmldoc/paramref)

```
<paramref name="personId"/>
```